# How to SQL select duplicates by one field and differs by another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table `person_log` with the following fields:

- `id`
- `timestamp`
- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `action`

with some example data

```
1;012545878;homer;simpson;eating
2;812345222;homer;simpson;watching tv
3;312322578;marge;simpson;cooking
4;114568568;bart;simpson;skating
5;015345345;bart;simpson;skating
```

Now I need to select all recordsets where `first_name` and `last_name` is the same and occurs at least two times, but `action` differs.

Resulting in selecting `id`s 1 and 2.

How can I do that? TIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table to get the persons having atleast 2 distinct actions and join it to the original table to get the other columns in the result.

```
select p.*
from person_log p 
join (select first_name,last_name
      from person_log
      group by first_name,last_name
      having count(*) >=2 and count(distinct action) >= 2) p1
on p1.first_name=p.first_name and p1.last_name=p.last_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by those field you want then have count greater or equal's to 2 as a table to be join to your main person_log table.

```
SELECT * FROM person_log p
JOIN (
SELECT first_name, last_name, action
group by first_name,last_name
having count(*) >=2 ) p2
on p.first_name=p2.first_name and p.last_name=p2.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number(), partition would let you group by firstname,lastname, and action:

```
select distinct id 
from (select pl.*,
         row_number() over (partition by first_name, last_name, action) as seqnum
  from person_log pl
 ) R
where seqnum > 1;
```